# Match different url start in regex, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

A bit confused with regex.

Url string can be either `'/item/new/url/bla/..'` or `'/#item/url/bla/bla/..'`

I need a regex to check start of the string. In pseudo code it can be described as:

```
(both "/#item/" or "/item/" at the start of a string should be true).test(url)
```

Comment: Use the optional ? .. `/^\/#?item\/.test(url)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^\/#?item\//.test('/#item/new/url/bla/'); // true
/^\/#?item\//.test('/item/new/url/bla/'); // true
```

Comment: @Kosmetika If this has solved your issue, please remember to click the tick under the votes and accept this answer.